# TYPO3 7.6 - How can I autoload composer packages?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I've created a TYPO3 7.6 extension with the extension builder. Now I want to add and autoload composer installed packages. I read that ext_autoload.php won't be loaded since TYPO3 version 7 in general. For this you should use the `ext_emconf.php` **OR** the `composer.json` in the root path of your extension.

So I've setup the following `composer.json` and installed it with the composer.phar.

```
{
    "require": {
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "v3.0.0-rc.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Package\\": "Classes"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now there is the `Vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src` as expected but the autoloader of TYPO3 doesn't find for example the `Vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src/Hybridauth.php` defined class `Hybridauth`. I've checked it with:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(get_declared_classes());
```

What did I miss? What do I have to add/change/rethink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. TYPO3 already autoloads already the psr-4 called environments. But I had to have add the autoloader of Hybridauth itself as well like:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Service;
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';

class SomeService extends \TYPO3\CMS\Sv\AbstractAuthenticationService{

  // ...

}
```

Comment: No, you don't. TYPO3 already indexes all php files in your installation. If your add new files, you have to flush the autoload cache to reinitiate this process. Also, dirname dirname dirname?

Answer (score 0):

Your json file content like below.

```
{
    "require": {
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "v3.0.0-rc.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "vendor\\extensionName\\": "Classes"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "Vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src/"
        ],
        "files": [
            "Vendor/hybridauth/hybridauth/src/Hybridauth.php"
        ]
    }
}
```